# Mjpg streaming in windows store app not working

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have a WPF app for MJpg streaming. It is working fine. I will include my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MjpegDecoder _mjpeg;

    public MainWindow()
    {    
        InitializeComponent();    
        _mjpeg = new MjpegDecoder();
        _mjpeg.FrameReady += _mjpeg_FrameReady;
    }

    void _mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        MjpgImage.Source = e.BitmapImage;   
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mjpeg.ParseStream(new Uri("Some IPaddress/mjpg/video.mjpg"));
    }      
}
```

I need to develop a windows store app for the same mjpg streaming. The same code i used there to develop my windows store app. But not working. The dll i used is MjpegDecoder, downloaded from codeplex. Please help me to develop a windows store app.

Thanks

Vishnu Aravind

Comment: What exactly does "But not working." mean?

Comment: really the e.BitmapImage gives a result of type System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitMapImage. It is not compatible with windows store app. The compatible type for windows store app is Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage. This casting makes the error. Also the dll MjpegDecoder is internally referring the normal .net dll presentationcore.dll. This PresentationCore.dll is not available in a windows store app. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.txt says there's the assembly MjpegProcessor.winmd - WinRT (AnyCPU, so will work with x86/x64 and ARM)

So I guess you just need to download / use the correct assembly.

Alternatively you can download the code and check yourself - it shouldn't even compile if the WinRt project references presentationcore.dll.

Comment: Ya perfect. One more help please,How to convert a Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitMapImage

Comment: To convert a Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitMapImage: import  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; call SetSource(myIBuffer.AsStream()) or SetSourceAsync(myIBuffer.AsStream())